Referencing instance method 'makeIterator()' on 'Collection' requires types to be equivalent
I have the following code where I'm using a generic class and another one that inherits it:
class StoredCollection<T>: RandomAccessCollection {
    
    public fileprivate(set) var items: [T] = []
    
    // RandomAccessCollection
    public var startIndex: Int { return self.items.startIndex }

    public var endIndex: Int { return self.items.endIndex }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
       return self.items.index(after: i)
    }

    open subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        get {
            return self.items[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.items[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}

class SynchronizedCollection<T>: StoredCollection<T> {
    
}

class Event {    }

let teams: SynchronizedCollection<Event> = SynchronizedCollection()

for team in teams {
    
}

Here the use of teams triggers a compilation error:

Referencing instance method 'makeIterator()' on 'Collection' requires
the types 'IndexingIterator<StoredCollection>' and
'IndexingIterator<SynchronizedCollection>' be equivalent

How one can fix that?

Avoid inheritance? What is SynchronizedCollection and why does it need to be a subclass of StoredCollection?

StoredCollection is a class that stores its content into a json file, and SynchronizedCollection communicates with a server on top of the storage

Why does that require SynchronizedCollection and StoredCollection to be a class, and why does that warrant inheritance? This might be an XY Problem. How about composition over inheritance?
